# No USB devices detected by VMware, arch linux host

Tags: usb, vmware, arch-linux

I'm having trouble connecting USB devices (e.g. flash drives) to a Windows XP guest, on an Arch Linux host, running VMware Player.
No USB devices appear anywhere in VMware, e.g. devices are not detected when I plug them in, and there is no section for USB devices in the removable devices menu.
I can mount and use USB devices outside of VMware.
I'm running a 3.1.3 kernel with VMware Player 4.0.1.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Mounted USBFS to /proc/bus/usb, then restarted VMware.
- Checked that USB controller is "Present" in the VMware Virtual Machine Settings

Comment: Strangely enough, changing the USB controller compatibility mode from USB 2.0 to USB 3.0 made it available in the Debian 7 guest. The external drive was plugged in in a USB 3.0 port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late maybe, but I found this problem too, using Debian. Solution was simple:
/etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator start
then restart VM.

More details at [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#USB_devices_not_recognized_by_VMware_workstation_8)

Answer (score 2):

Run `vmware-usbarbitrator`:

```
# vmware-usbarbitrator
```

To see what it is going on behind the scenes, run:

```
# vmware-usbarbitrator --kill && vmware-usbarbitrator -f
```

You may need to close and re-open `player` to see the changes.

Note the [VMware Documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-95232C52-C5A8-471B-A6A1-C7323A97FECA.html) is incorrect and outdated as it still refers to `/proc/bus/usb` which was removed in Linux kernel 3.5.

Comment: After detect with this commend, i resolve my issue, i could not show USB 3.0 storage device, because, i am not check "Show all USB input devices" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much experience with VMWare Player but on VMWare ESX you need to tell ESX to 'pass-through' the device to a specific VM. Is using USB devices even possible on Player?